# FFmpeg -shortest not working when using -filter_complex with audio and video filters

Tags: linux, windows, audio, ffmpeg, video

Pretty much the exact same issue was described [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3789) several years ago, but the 'solution' given, while it works, is more inconvenient and doesn't explain why the actual command in question does not work.

I'm using the following command to mix the audio of `input.mp4` with `song.m4a` and ensure that the dimensions of my output file are even numbers:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i song.m4a -filter_complex \
[0:a][1:a]amix[s0];[0:v]pad=height=ceil(ih/2)*2:width=ceil(iw/2)*2[s1] \
-map [s0] -map [s1] -shortest output.mp4
```

`input.mp4` is only about 20 seconds long, but `song.m4a` is about 8 minutes long. I want to mix both the audio streams together, so that the first 20 seconds of `song.m4a` plays alongside the original audio of `input.m4a`. To ensure that the output file does not become 8 minutes long, I'm using the `-shortest` option, which should make FFmpeg stop encoding once it hits the shortest audio/video stream. However, in the command above, `-shortest` seems to be not working entirely.

When I separate the audio and video filters into 2 separate `-filter_complex`s, it works as intended (doing this was also the solution given in the issue a linked at the top):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i song.m4a -filter_complex \
[0:a][1:a]amix[s0] -filter_complex [0:v]pad=height=ceil(ih/2)*2:width=ceil(iw/2)*2[s1] \
-map [s0] -map [s1] -shortest output.mp4
```

Same with if I remove the video filters entirely:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i song.m4a -filter_complex [0:a][1:a]amix[s0] -map [s0] -map 0:v -shortest output.mp4
```

Using the above 2 commands results in a 20-second long video as intended.

I guess my question is why is `-shortest` made redundant when combining both audio and video filters in a single `-filter_complex` argument? Is this a bug, or the intended behaviour? How can I get it to work as intended with just one -filter_complex?

I'm using a self-compiled FFmpeg build on Linux (using the most recent Git version as of writing this) but I can confirm I can also recreate the issue with the official Linux AND Windows builds as well, even when using different audio and video files too.

---

The issue can be easily recreated using these commands:

```
// Create video file
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2 -f lavfi -i sine=2000 -t 5 -y input.mp4

// Create song file
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i sine=500 -t 10 -y song.m4a

// Combine both files (-shortest should work here but it does not)
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i song.m4a -lavfi [0:a][1:a]amix[s0];[0:v]null[s1] -map [s0] -map [s1] -shortest -y output.mp4
```

I've also [opened a ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9487) on the FFmpeg Trac which give more useful information in it's replies.

Comment: It's not intended behaviour. I'll debug this in a few days. Remind me if I don't post an update in a week.

Comment: @Gyan Thank you very much - I'll be interested to find out what is causing it! Sounds like it may be a long-standing issue....

Comment: Hey @Gyan any update on this so far? Much appreciated

Comment: Did some initial debugging. Somewhat complicated.